# How do I get rid of the square brackets around my event and date?

Tags: python

```
calendar = []
while True:
    choice = input ("enter a,b,c,d or e")
    if choice == "e":
        print ("you have quitted this program")
        break #to quit the entire program
    if choice == "a":
        newevent = input ("enter the name of an event you want to add")
        y= int(input("enter the year of your event"))
        m = int(input("enter the month of your event"))
        d = int(input("enter the day of your event"))
        h = int(input("enter the hour of your event"))
        mi = int(input("enter the minute of your event"))
        calendar.append ([newevent,y,m,d,h,mi])
        print (calendar)
        f = open("calendar.txt","w")
        f.write (str(calendar)+"\n")
        f.close()



f = open('calendar.txt','r')
st = f.readlines()
print (st)

for i in range (0,len(st)):
    st[i] = st[i].strip("\n")
    print (st)
    f.close()
```

This is my output:

```
[['swim', 2020, 4, 2, 3, 2]]
["[['swim', 2020, 4, 2, 3, 2]]\n"]
["[['swim', 2020, 4, 2, 3, 2]]"]
```

I want to get rid of the square brackets around my code to make it swim,2020,4,2,3,2. Do I have to open the file before `while True`?

Answer (score 0):

For ***just*** stripping the end characters, use:

```
"[1, 2, 3]"[1:-1]
```

which will do just that. Strip the first character from left and right. But in case you want to save text or anything else, it'll require more work on your side to handle such special cases.

When saving you call `f.write (str(calendar)+"\n")` which if encounters a `list` does this:

```
[1, 2, 3]
    |
    v
"[1, 2, 3]"
```

if you want to convert back into Python list, simply use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) on that via:

```
from ast import literal_eval
mylist = literal_eval("[1, 2, 3]")
print(type(mylist))
print(mylist[0])
```

Or instead of plain `str(object)` use a better structure when saving to a file such as [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: @amanda I added string slicing to my answer, but otherwise not really. What you do is a kind of serialization. If you want to serialize the data, you need a proper way to deserialize them afterwards. JSON is one of the structures, but you can use a different one as well. Or - don't call `str(object)` and save it item by item from the list. Each custom approach however will require more work on your side, so just use already well-defined structure that supports (de)serialization via a Python package.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
import json

calendar = []
while True:
    choice = input ("enter a,b,c,d or e : ")
    if choice == "e":
        print ("you have quitted this program")
        break #to quit the entire program
    if choice == "a":
        newevent = input ("enter the name of an event you want to add : ")
        y= int(input("enter the year of your event : "))
        m = int(input("enter the month of your event : "))
        d = int(input("enter the day of your event : "))
        h = int(input("enter the hour of your event : "))
        mi = int(input("enter the minute of your event : "))
        data = [newevent,y,m,d,h,mi]
        calendar.append(data)

with open("calendar.json","w") as f:
    f.write(f"{json.dumps(calendar)}")

with open('calendar.json','r') as f:
    st = f.read()
    j_data = json.loads(st)

    print(j_data)
```

Comment: thank you!!!!!! is there a simpler way like using the strip function???

Answer (score 0):

Hy, since you want to remove the long brackets of the array. You can use the strip function.And remember to convert your array to a string if not aready
For example:

```
str1="['a','b']"
str1=str1.strip('[]')
print(str1)
```

This will give a string 'a','b'
.Hope this helps you